# How to use exclude pattern(.pdb,.xml) while zip the directory files in cake?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I want to exclude some format files like PDB, XML and BMP files in my zip package.

Please help me on this http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.IO/ZipAliases/B6C83EAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the built in Zip aliases will only create a standard Zip file not 7zip, if it's only assemblies you want to include in your archive you can use the  [Zip(DirectoryPath rootPath, FilePath outputPath, string pattern)](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.IO/ZipAliases/2833634B) overload.

Example usage:

```
 Zip("./", "dllfiles.zip", "./*.dll");
```

If you have several different file types, then I would recommend you create a directory with the artifacts you want to archive and then just zip that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use linq in the cakebuild,  script. Something along these lines:

```
var ignoredExts = new string[] { ".bmp", ".xml", ".pdb" };
var files = GetFiles("./bin/Release/*.*")
    .Where(f => !ignoredExts.Contains(f.GetExtension().ToLower()));
Zip("./", "cakeassemblies.zip", files);
```